# Efficiently storing sparsely populated 2D grid

Tags: java, c, design-patterns

I have a huge map, and tiles on it.
It's a dungeon, so there clearly is a lot of empty space, where I'd store nulls.

Obviously, having a huge 2D array is an option, but I think it's not the most elegant one. Also when I want to save it to file, it's not very neat to store tons of null marks.

Something like this, but A LOT bigger:

```
+--------------+
|   X     X    |
| XXX    XX    |
|   XXXXXXX    |
|    X   XX    |
|   XXX   XXX  |
|     X   X    |
+--------------+
```

What other alternatives to width×height array do I have?

Only something like `Map<IntCoord, Tile>`? Or is there some widely-used solution for similar scenario?

Comment: Sure, but there is items in the corridors, monsters and all. I need to store the actual tiles, not only how they are connected.

Comment: Hm.. let's say 256x256, that should suffice. But it depends, the level is randomly generated and I'm not yet sure if I want to restrain it.

Comment: If it's 256*256 I'd have no issues with storing it in a 2d array. It'd become an issue if you had maybe...billions (?) of tiles. For storing on disk, the map (or vector of pairs?) solution seems smart for compression, if the map dimensions are easily restored.

Comment: Okay, Fair enough. It's easier too, I'm probably over-engineering things again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things you could use:

1. 2D Array.
2. List.
3. Map.

2D Arrays are the best, unless your map is huge, in which case you could use Lists.

---

2D Array:

Pros: It has the fastest lookup times.

Cons: It (most likely) takes the most memory.

The lookup times probably heavily outweigh the memory costs. Unless your dungeon is hundreds of thousands of tiles large, this is probably the way to go.

---

List (probably ArrayList):

Pros: Only storing items you need.

Cons: Lookup times will be horrible.

While Lists will use less memory, it will take a lot longer to find a tile or item, as you'll have to iterate over the List to find something matching a location.

---

Map (probably HashMap):

Pros: Each location will be linked to an object per map, so lookup times will be ok.

Cons: Lookup times will not be optimal, will use moderate amounts of memory.

Maps are in between Lists and Arrays. The will use up more memory than arrays, but have better lookup times than Lists.

---

2D Arrays are the best because of the lookup time. On most modern computers, memory is not a concern. If it is, you can always cache areas not currently being used to files and dynamically load them as needed.

Comment: Regarding performance of using a List, I disagree with your analysis. The lookup times depend on your usage pattern. In particular, if you want to iterate over positions, then your lookup times could actually be _faster_ than a sufficiently sparse 2D array because you will avoid a lot of `null` checks. If the access pattern has any sort of locality, then you may be able to iterate from your last accessed location for significant speedup. But even with a random access pattern, lookups are only **`log n`** using binary search, not linear.

Comment: You can also have hybrid solutions such as 2D List or 2D Map. Ie, a (sparse) List of the rows which have things in them, each of which contains a (sparse) List of the cells in that row with whatever is there. Same goes for Map (use x coord as key into outer Map, and use y coord as key into inner Map; values of outer Map are inner Maps).

Comment: @SchighSchagh That's a valid point, but I would imagine that for a dungeon game, the majority of the array accesses would be localized around the cell where the current player is, and there probably wouldn't be a whole lot of iterating over the entire array. Also, there's no reason one couldn't combine the two approaches, and keep lists of items and objects in the dungeon that you might otherwise have to scan for. That way you'd get the best of both worlds. Array lookups for things where array lookups would be faster, and list traversal for things where list traversal would be faster.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I disagree. Finding a value in a List requires some sort of searching algorithm, probably iteration (ArrayList), maybe binary search (some sort of SortedList). Finding a value in a Map requires iteration (in a really bad map) or binary search (in a regular Map). Finding a value in a 2D array is O(1), vs. O(n) for iteration and O(log n) for binary search.

Comment: What about a quadtree? It can store empty space really good, and you still have all the advantages of binary lookups.

Comment: Also @MightyPork you shouldn't have `null` values in your 2D array, but follow the Null Object Pattern. For example, create a type of tile named `BLANK` and use that instead of null.

Comment: @Jongware imo anything but a 2D array is severly overcomplicating things. I only included the other two because they were mentioned. In theory, you could use a quadtree, in practice, anything but a 2D array is kinda pointless.

Comment: @AnubianNoob What's the benefit of having NullTile, except avoiding null checking? How's it better? (I see all downsides - harder testing for what to save and what not, bigger memory usage...)

Comment: @MightyPork What is the size of your dungeon? Memory usage is probably not a concern. If you don't follow the Null Object Pattern and use nulls, then you will have to check for null. Also, nulls would be an object type -- such as a floor or wall. What if you want differant types of 'nulls?' What would you do then? Also, null object pattern makes your code much easier to read. You can do something like `getTile().isPassable()` and not have to worry about null characters. With nulls, you'll have to test if it is null and then make a hard-coded default value which is harder to test, not easier.

Comment: Also this would be smaller when written to a file because you don't need to store the location of the tiles, you can just store all the tiles, without having to worry about position. If you use RLE this would be _even_ shorter because you don't have to do duplicates.

Comment: I don't think RLE is an option for me (it's not true-false, there are metadata in the tiles), but I've adopted the null pattern anyway - it will be useful for generation (I'll make corridors with A* between room centers).

Comment: Guys, look here to see where this is going: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bmjdv1uCEAEIw9Y.png:large

Answer (score 2):

I won't comment much on how to store the data in memory at run-time, since Anubian's answer seems to have covered that well enough. I also agree with him that unless you have some severe memory restrictions and/or your dungeons are truly massive (like 10,000 x 10,000), then there's no real reason **not** to just store it as a 2D array. The coding effort you save and the run-time performance you gain, will almost certainly outweigh whatever space-efficiency advantage you might gain by using lists, maps, etc. And if you really do have insufficient RAM to store your dungeons, you could always segment them into blocks and load only the blocks you need at any given time (typically, whatever block the player is currently on, plus maybe a few adjacent blocks so that there's no noticeable load-time lag when the player moves from one block to the next). That's a bit more work than just one big array, but still probably easier than storing the data in some sparse data structure and then having to compute the contents of each cell every single time it gets accessed.

As for storing it to file, however, you might want to consider [Run Length Encoding (RLE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

It's trivial to write the encode and decode functions for RLE, and you can arbitrarily decide on your own syntax and character set, etc.

The problem you're trying to solve (efficient encoding of a 2D grid) is actually very similar to the problem of storing states in Conway's Game of Life simulation programs, and one of the most common file formats they use is RLE: http://conwaylife.com/wiki/Run_Length_Encoded.

Your example dungeon is similar enough to a Game of Life object/state/whatever that you could even just use the same exact RLE encoding that they use, in which case you'd get something like this for your example dungeon:

```
# Optional comment lines
#   (perhaps a dungeon name and/or description?)
x = 14, y = 6
3bo5bo$b3o4b2o$3b7o$4bo3b2o$3b3o3b3o$5bo3bo!
```

Comment: Actually I'm now saving it using my ION binary data storage system, and the format is somewhat like () = binary mark: (MAP)(WIDTH)(HEIGHT)(ENTRY)(X)(Y)(ID)(..extra data..)(ENTRY)....(ENTRY)...(END)
so I think I've solved the efficiency of saving this way. Null tiles are simply skipped. If the map happens **not** to be sparse, then I will have overhead of two INTs and one SHORT per tile. Not too bad, I guess.